# How to view Graph Reduction/Graph Representation for a Haskell program?

Tags: programming-languages, compilers, haskell

I know that under the hood, for a Haskell program, the GHC compiler uses graph reduction for optimization. Is there any way to view this graphical representation of the program? I haven't been able to find an existing plugin that, given a Haskell program, produces its graphical representation. I am relatively new to Haskell.

Are there research tools available to study and manipulate such graphs?

Comment: Great question! Welcome to the site. I don't know the answer, but maybe someone else does.

Comment: may I suggest that there is maybe an isomorphism betweem the graph reduction done by GHC for optimization (and I guess evaluation/compilation) and the partial evaluation through meta-interpretation for optimization, as seen in Logic Programming (and perhaps tracing JIT interpreter systems such as PyPy)?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to [CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)!

I cannot present the underlying algorithms themselves, just the concepts they use.

The **normal form** (**NF**) of some expression is basically its result, like `42`, `Just 1`, `\ x -> 1 + x`.

The **weak head normal form** (**WHNF**) is some expression which is one of three:

1. A lambda: `\ x -> x + 5 * 6`. The **NF** is `\ x -> x + 30`.
2. Data constructor: `(3, 2 + 5)`. The **NF** is `(3, 7)`. It could be partially applied: `(,) (2 * 5)`. The **NF** is `\ x -> (10, x)`.
3. Partially applied built-in function: `(+) (2 * 8)`. The **NF** is `\ x -> 16 + x`.

As one can see, **WHNF** generalizes **NF**.

So, what have graphs got to do with this? Well, one can understand `f e1 e2 ... en` as a graph with a node `f` which is connected with `n` other nodes: `e1, e2, ..., en`. Evaluation is the reduction of the nodes<sup>**1**</sup>. To show why this is actually very cool I am going to use [a picture which I stumbled upon on Wikipedia and HaskellWiki not so long ago](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Right-fold-transformation.png):

[image: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Right-fold-transformation.png]

So, what is going on in this picture? The idea is simple: when working with lists, we have a binary operation `(:)` and some initial value `[]`. When we are folding, we have a binary operation `f` and some initial value `z`. The data structure does not change - only the nodes of our graph. To get the complete result (**NF**, that is), we reduce the graph.

**(Please note that the initial `1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : 5 : []` could not have been reduced any further; in (pseudo-)haskell the lists are: `data [a] = a : [a] | []`.)**

---

<sup>**1**</sup>Some technical details on evaluation (the basic tools to manipulate graphs, just as you have asked). The programmer might force the reduction. `seq x y` forces its first argument to the **WHNF** and returns the second (being basically `flip const` magically strict in the first argument). More formally:

> [...`seq x y` means that whenever `y` is evaluated to weak head normal form, `x` is also evaluated to weak head normal form.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6889335/11143763)

If the programmer wants to do the same for the **NF**, they should take a look at [`Control.DeepSeq.deepseq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.4.4.0/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html).